# Сериализация в String

Tags: java, android, сериализация

Нужно сериализовать объект и сохранить его в SharedPreferences. А туда можно писать только примитивные типы или String.
Я решил сериализовать в ByteArrayOutputStream, получить массив байтов и создать из массива байтов String.
Но при восстановлении объекта вылетает ошибка:
java.io.StreamCorruptedException.
Подозреваю что тут проблема с кодировкой String, так как если исключить из цепочки преобразование в String все проходит успешно.
Вот мой тестовый код:

```
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "TEST START");
        OpenGLRenderer.State a=renderer.onSaveState();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(a);
        String string=new String(baos.toByteArray());
        ByteArrayInputStream bais=new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes());
        ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(bais);
        OpenGLRenderer.State aa= (OpenGLRenderer.State) ois.readObject();
        Log.i(TAG,"TEST COMPLETE");
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"TEST ERROR",e);
    }
```

Как правильно запихнуть/извлечь сериализованный объект в String?

Comment: я думаю, лучше использовать [`Base64.encode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html?hl=ru) вместо `new String`

Comment: @zRrr , спасибо, правда решение я уже нашел, используя кодировку "ISO-8859-1".

Comment: Обычно байты в строку сохраняют в виде HEX последовательности.